# How to make a table from given pets to aggregate the count of the other pets?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am writing a PySpark code from the following table.

| user | pets |
| --- | --- |
| aa | [["dog"], ["cat"], ["lizard"]] |
| bb | [["dog"], ["spider"]] |
| cc | [["dog"], ["cat"], ["monkey"]] |
| ... | ... |

Using explode_outer, I unnested the table to below.

| user | pets |
| --- | --- |
| aa | "dog" |
| aa | "cat" |
| aa | "lizard" |
| bb | "dog" |
| bb | "spider" |
| cc | "dog" |
| cc | "cat" |
| cc | "monkey" |
| ... | ... |

I would like to make another table that contains these data below.

| pet | dog | cat | lizard | spider | monkey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| cat | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| lizard | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| spider | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| monkey | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

For instance, in terms of spider, it only lives with dog in the user 'bb'. So that if the data is meaningfully large, I can answer the quote, "Find top 3 pets that are the best suits with your dog."

However, I have no idea how to design appropriate code from the second table to the third one.

Comment: How exactly is the second table made from first table?

Comment: Let's say the first table is df. second_df = df.select(explode_outer(df.pets['name']).alias("pets")).distinct().filter(col("pets").isNotNull()).collect()

Comment: Did `Rene's` answer help you?

Comment: Not exactly but the idea of combination was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution based only on the Spark engine. Finding all the combinations, separating them into columns and doing a `crosstab`. The result omits repeating entries.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('aa', [["dog"], ["cat"], ["lizard"]]),
     ('bb', [["dog"], ["spider"]]),
     ('cc', [["dog"], ["cat"], ["monkey"]])],
    ['user', 'pets'])

df = df.withColumn('pets', F.flatten('pets'))
combinations = (F.filter(
    F.transform(
        F.flatten(F.transform(
            'pets',
            lambda x: F.arrays_zip(F.array_repeat(x, F.size('pets')), 'pets')
        )),
        lambda x: F.array(x['0'], x['pets'])
    ),
    lambda x: x[0] < x[1]
))
df = df.withColumn('pets', F.explode(combinations))
df = df.withColumn('pet0', F.col('pets')[0])
df = df.withColumn('pet1', F.col('pets')[1])

df = df.crosstab("pet0", "pet1")

df.show()
# +---------+---+------+------+------+
# |pet0_pet1|dog|lizard|monkey|spider|
# +---------+---+------+------+------+
# |      dog|  0|     1|     1|     1|
# |      cat|  2|     1|     1|     0|
# +---------+---+------+------+------+
```

Comment: It seems only counting zero to one case (No monkey and spider rows). Can you modify it to including reversed cases?

Comment: I solved it using UDF with combinations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. Hope this helps to solve your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user':['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'pets':[['dog', 'cat', 'lizard'], ['dog', 'spider'], ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey']]}).explode('pets')
combinations = []
for g in df1.groupby('user'):
    combinations += [x for x in itertools.combinations(g[1].pets, 2)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int), columns=df1.pets.unique(), index=df1.pets.unique())
for x in combinations:
    df2.at[x[0], x[1]] += 1
    df2.at[x[1], x[0]] += 1
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
        dog  cat  lizard  spider  monkey
dog       0    2       1       1       1
cat       2    0       1       0       1
lizard    1    1       0       0       0
spider    1    0       0       0       0
monkey    1    1       0       0       0
```